# How to access AWS Parameter Store from Flutter application

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-parameter-store

I Have a Flutter application where I'm utilizing a key that is stored in AWS parameter store. How should I obtain this key to Flutter application?

edit: I have the AWS Amplify Libraries in use in the Flutter application.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation pages of AWS Amplify. Environment secrets are values stored in parameter store.

> Accessing an environment secret during a build is similar to accessing
> environment variables, except that environment secrets are stored in
> `process.env.secrets` as a JSON string.

You can read environment variables in flutter like this:

```
static const SOME_VAR = String.fromEnvironment('SOME_VAR');
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html